# ShellScript: Whats the diff between % and %% here?

Tags: bash, shell

I am a shell script newbie. I want to know the difference between

```
${var%pattern}
```

and

```
${var%%pattern}
```

Thanks

Comment: yes, i am currently using bash shell.

Comment: @docgnome: bash, dash, ksh and zsh all support that syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> ```
> ${parameter%word}
> ${parameter%%word}
> ```
>
> The `word` is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion. If the              pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of `parameter`,  then  the               result  of  the  expansion  is  the  expanded value of `parameter` with the shortest               matching pattern (the "%" case) or the  longest  matching  pattern  (the  "%%"               case)  deleted.

Here's an example of what the difference is:

```
$ VAR=abcdefabcdef
$ echo ${VAR%def*}
abcdefabc
$ echo ${VAR%%def*}
abc
```

Notice that there are two possible matches for `def*` at the end of `$VAR`: both "defabcdef" and just "def" match. With the "%" the shortest possible match for the pattern `def*` is deleted, so the trailing "def" is removed. With the "%%" the longest possible match is deleted, so "defabcdef" bites the dust.

Comment: thanks, i was dumb enough not to know that we can find these in man pages!

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash`:

> ```
>    ${parameter%word}
>    ${parameter%%word}
> ```
>
> Remove  matching  suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to
>   produce a pattern just as in pathname
>   expansion.  If the pattern
>                 matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of
>   parameter, then the result of the
>   expansion is the  expanded  value  of
>                 parameter  with  the  shortest matching pattern (the `%''
>   case) or the longest matching pattern
>   (the`%%'' case) deleted.
>                 If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is
>   applied to each positional parameter
>   in turn, and the expansion is
>                 the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with @ or *, the pattern
>   removal operation is applied to
>                 each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.